# Javascript repeat/loop help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript

```
$('.goto1').click(function() { 
    $('#mttslider').cycle(0); 
    return false; 
});
```

What I would like is for it to repeat like so:

```
$('.goto1').click(function() { 
    $('#mttslider').cycle(0); 
    return false; 
}); 

$('.goto2').click(function() { 
    $('#mttslider').cycle(1); 
    return false; 
}); 

$('.goto3').click(function() { 
        $('#mttslider').cycle(2); 
        return false; 
    }); 

etc...
```

This is so that I can get every trigger - .goto(n) - to trigger the cycle function.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: give all your `goto#` items another generic `goto` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('[class^=goto]').click(function() { 
    var index = parseInt( this.className.replace('goto',''), 10 );
    $('#mttslider').cycle(index); 
    return false; 
});
```

This will works if you element has no `class` except `goto1, goto2` etc.

Comment: Nice work. Was working on something else, but this is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
var listener = function(index){
 var selector = '.goto'+ index;
 $(selector).click(function() { 
    $('#mttslider').cycle(index-1); 
    return false; 
 }); 
}
```

Now you can call the *listener* function from i to n to register new event listeners and call *cycle* function with variable index value

e.g:

```
listener(3);
listener(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

well assuming you know the range of `n` to begin with
I might do something like this:

```
var slider = $('#mtslider');

for(var i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
    (function(j){ 
        $('.goto' + j).on('click', function(){
            slider.cycle(j)
        });
    })(i);
}
```

since `$('#mtslider')` is referencing an Id, I'm assuming it doesn't change, so you don't have to run the jquery selector multiple times.  Beyond that, just loop through each `int` in the range `[1,n]` and use a closure to create the click handler.  If you don't use a closure, the value of `i` will most likely be different once the item is clicked.

If `n` is unknown, you can use a single selector, similar to the previous answer, but without the caveat of having `goto(n)` being the first class.

```
$('class~="goto"]').on('click', function(){ 
    var i = /goto(\d+)/.exec(this.className)[1];
    slider.cycle(i);
});
```